# Confusion about Conley's definition of an attractor

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I'm reading a paper where Conley's definition of an attractor is used. It goes as follows:
Let $(X, f)$ be a dynamical system. The $ω$-limit of a set $Y⊆X$ is $ω(Y)=\cap_{n>0}\overline{\cup_{m>n}f^m(Y)}$. A non-empty set $Y ⊆ X$ is an attractor if there exists an
open set $U$ such that $f(\overline{U}) ⊆ U$ and $Y = ω(U )$.

The part that confuses me is the condition $f(\overline{U}) ⊆ U$. Why is $Y$ not an attractor if this condition is not met?

My apologies if I am missing something obvious, but I'm a physicist and my background in topology is fairly limited.

Comment: If $Y$ is an attractor you want it to actract an open set surrounding it, so $Y\subset U$ and $\omega(U)=Y$, I think that $f(\overline U)\subset U$ is a way to guarantee that you don't have $Y$ open and $\omega(Y)=Y$ hence $Y$ is an attractor.

Comment: @MatíasUres That makes sense. Thanks!